# List of packages for RH 5.x

Tags: linux, redhat, sssd

I need to install SSSD onto some of my client's servers, but a few of them are pretty old. Is there a list of all of the packages in the repository for a specific release of redhat?

Specifically I need to see what is the newest version of SSSD that is supported by RH 5.3, 5.4, and 5.4 Beta without downloading them.

Comment: 5.3 and 5.4? Why are your systems years out of date?

Comment: RH 5.3, 5.4, and 5.4 Beta are very old versions of RHEL 5. The latest available version of RHEL5, and the only version that should be used these days, is [RHEL5.11](https://access.redhat.com/articles/3078#RHEL5]). Anything older has missed out on security and stability updates and is at risk of being hacked. Consider a move to RHEL6 or RHEL7, which are the new versions of RHEL.

Answer (score 4):

[sssd was added to RHEL 5](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/5.6_Release_Notes/ar01s06.html) with the RHEL 5.6 service pack.

Bring the systems up to date, (the current release is RHEL 5.11) and you will then have access to it.

And, [**do not run RHEL without a subscription**](https://serverfault.com/a/537570/126632).

Answer (score 1):

To see the latest version of sssd that is supported by RHEL5, use `yum info` and `yum check-update`.

```
stefanl@rhel5:~ $ cat /etc/issue
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.11 (Tikanga)
Kernel \r on an \m

stefanl@rhel5:~ $ yum info sssd --quiet
Available Packages
Name       : sssd
Arch       : x86_64
Version    : 1.5.1
Release    : 71.el5
```

A quick note about RHEL version numbers. The version is RHEL major.minor, as in RHEL 5.11. Anything older then the latest minor version number is obsoleted as soon as the next minor version is released and should be updated. Red Hat does not maintain separate version trees for RHEL 5.3, 5.4, 5.11, etc. They maintain packages for RHEL 5, which apply to all RHEL versions.