# Files in /etc/yum.repo.d don't seem to be read

Tags: linux, redhat, yum

I have the following my `/etc/yum.repo.d` directory:

```
[fixnetix-base]
name=Fixnetix Base
baseurl=http://10.20.82.149/os/rhel/x86_64/6.8
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1

[fixnetix-security]
name=Fixnetix Security
baseurl=http://10.20.82.149/repos/security/FXNX/6/latest
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1

[fixnetix-infra]
name=Fixnetix Infrastructure
mirrorlist=file:///etc/yum.repos.d/mirrorlist
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

When I run yum repolist, no repository information is shown:

```
# yum repolist
repolist: 0
```

This is the effectively the same behavior as if there was no files in the directory.

This is fresh redhat 6 build with selinux enabled.

Comment: post /etc/yum.conf

Comment: `[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=0
installonly_limit=3`

Comment: What is the file named ?

Comment: It has a .repo suffix

Comment: You should put the file in `/etc/yum.repos.d`, not `/etc/yum.repo.d`. You also [need an active RHEL subscription](http://serverfault.com/q/537568/126632).